# Execute JQuery code after view has changed

Tags: ember.js

I'm using Foundation tooltips on the page with query-parameters - they control what elements are displayed, acts as filter  basically.

When user change filter and new elements are displayed tooltip stops to work as it needs to be reattached to the new elements - `$(document).foundation('tooltip', 'reflow');` so I wonder what is the correct way to execute this code after view is re-rendered.

For sure this must go to the view layer, but I can't find appropriate event http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.View.html#events

Comment: why shouldn't you be sharing some code to look at?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can think of a few ways

```
export default Ember.Route.extend({
    queryParams: {
      <name-of-query-param>: { refreshModel: true }
    }
```

Or have an trigger `this.refresh()` on the [route](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Route.html#method_refresh).

Or in the controller, observe the query param and execute the event in a [loop](http://guides.emberjs.com/v1.10.0/understanding-ember/run-loop/)

Comment: thank you, `rerender` seems to be most clear solution

Comment: you mean `this.refresh()` ?

Comment: Oops, yes it's `this.refresh()`

Answer (score 1):

Use an observer function like this:

```
$document: Ember.computed( function() {
  return $(document);
}),

updateTooltips: Ember.observer('theFilter', function() {
  Ember.run.later( function() {
    this.get('$document').foundation('tooltip', 'reflow');
  }.bind(this));
})
```

As further improvement, you can abstract the tooltips code into a service.

Comment: what is the reason to wrap $(document) inside CP?

Comment: Then it will be cached and not recalculated every time you request tooltip reflow.

Answer (score 1):

You might wrap each element in a Component and use `didInsertElement` event. You could access jQuery object for the component as `this.$()`

```
export default Ember.Component.extend({

  setTooltip: function() {
    this.$(). ... //here your jQuery
  }.on('didInsertElement')

});
```

Comment: that might work, but unfortunately zurb's tooltip is so bad with dynamically inserted elements that insertion/deletion of the components should occur only after tooltip is hidden and I think this is easier to manage outside of component.